# Android: Active Scanning for wifi networks

Tags: android, wifi, network-scan

Is it possible to perform an active wifi scan on android without using the, according to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6234728/missing-method-in-android-net-wifi-wifimanager), undocumented API call `startScanActive()`?

Are there any other possibilities to do this and perform an active scan?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, it seems that is just not possible.
One possible "Workaround" to use startScanActive() is described [here](https://devmaze.wordpress.com/2011/01/19/using-com-android-internal-part-5-summary-and-example/), but that is not guaranteed to work.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the WifiManager class, startScan() and getScanResults() methods

Comment: Yes, I know that, but afaik this initiates only a passive Scan. To solve my Problem I need to Initiate an active Scan