# Android WifiManager.startScan() - active or passive scanning?

Tags: android, wifimanager, probe

A couple of posts on SO including [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9380362/android-active-scanning-for-wifi-networks) imply that WifiManager.startScan() only scans passively, waiting for APs to send out beacons, instead of actively sending out probe requests.

Well, I downloaded CommView for WiFi to just check this out for myself, and I find I see a probe request when I use startScan() in my app. The device is a Motorola Atrix.

[image: CommView probe request on WifiManager.startScan()]

So what am I missing?!

PVS

Comment: I have no idea whether WifiManager.startScan() is passive or not, but just because an answer is accepted in a question doesn't make it a fact. If you have evidence to the contrary, I recommend trusting what you see not what others have told you. I've seen plenty of wrong answers here.

Comment: May even be dependent on what power-saving profile is active..

Comment: I cannot find any documentation indicating whether startScan() is passive or active. This post says "looking for 802.11 APs is primarily active.": http://superuser.com/questions/128166/is-looking-for-wi-fi-access-points-purely-passive